# Как достать jpeg файлы из одного большого бинарного файла

Tags: java

Есть кеш галереи , это один большой бинарный файл с изображениями внутри , проверял hex редактором ,  там файлы jpg  размещены последовательно (но вначале , и между ними есть разделительные байты) 
Как с помощью Java можно обработать этот файл и достать картинки . Судя по структуре jpeg файл начинается из байтов FF D8 и заканчивается FF D9 , хотел как то считывать и записывать в новые файлы  , но по неопытности не знаю как точно это реализовать.

Comment: Что за формат файла ?Возможно это известный формат. Может поискать описание формата ?  возможно кто-то написал уже парсер.

Comment: Читать от разделителя до разделителя в буфер, а на разделителях записывать буфер в файл.

Comment: JaponDemon, кэш галереи miui

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev,принцип как это сделать я знаю , но хорошо не знаю  Java , чтобы это реализовать

Comment: @Саша вы ждёте, что кто-то напишет код за вас?

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, я жду чтобы кто-то написал общий принцип такого парсера

Answer (score 1):

Код примерно такой:

```
FileInputStream sc;
FileOutputStream pw;
sc = new FileInputStream(new File("input.xz"));
int r;
boolean ff;
boolean begin;
int index=0;
while((r=sc.read())!=-1){
    if(r==0xFF){
        ff=true;
        continue;//исключение последовательностей FF FF FF
    }
    if(ff==true){
        ff=false;
        if(r==0xD8){
            begin=true;
            pw=new FileOutputStream(new File("output"+index+".jpg"));
            pw.write(0xFF);
            pw.write(0xD8);
            readjpg(sc, pw);
            begin=false;
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Очень важно определить правильно конец файла jpeg пропустив шапку.

```
void readjpg(FileInputStream sc, PrintWriter pw) throws IOException{
    int r;
    boolean ff;
    while((r=sc.read())!=-1){
        pw.write(r);
        if(r==0xFF){
            ff=true;
            continue;//исключение последовательностей FF FF FF
        }
        //заголовки
        if((r==0xFE) || (r==0xDB) || ((0xC0>=r)&&(r<=0cC2)) || (r==0xC4) ){
            r=sc.read();
            pw.write(r);
            int i=0|(r<<8);
            r=sc.read();
            pw.write(r);
            i=i|r;
            i-=2;
            while(i>0){
                r=sc.read(); pw.write(r); i--;
            }
            continue;
        }
        //старт
        if(r==0xDA){
            r=sc.read(); pw.write(r);
            int i=0|(r<<8);
            r=sc.read(); pw.write(r);
            i=i|r;
            i-=2;
            while(i>0){
                r=sc.read(); pw.write(r); i--;
            }
            boolean ff;
            while((r=sc.read())!=-1){
                pw.write(r);
                if(r==0xFF){
                    ff=true;
                    continue;//исключение последовательностей FF FF FF
                }
                if(ff==true){
                    ff=false;
                    if(r==0xD8){
                        pw.close();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```